# Fastest way to find a path along a grid of dots, given a specified start and end, touching every dot without retracing a route?

Tags: puzzle

How to solve this problem in the fastest way possible?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Although some may question posting a puzzle on mathSE, personally, I think the question about how to analytically attack this problem does (at least potentially) relate to math.  Per the comment of @saulspatz, please see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) re protocol on mathSE questions.  Also, to repeat, your work/analysis belongs in the (edited) question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: For convenience to reviewers, I edited your question to embed the diagram directly into the question.  In general, see [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for options of embedding a diagram.  Note also, my (unusual) `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pPTY.png" width="600">` method of enlarging the diagram.

Comment: The spoiler is that you can do it in $6$, but [it is not obvious](https://youtu.be/EKQANDiFoAU?t=31).

Comment: Think outside the box. Literally